# Commitment scheme for a possible unordered growing collection of elements

Tags: commitments, hash-tree, accumulators

Merkle trees can be used for vector commitment scheme. In particular given two sequences S, S' with the same elements in the same order the merkle root for S will be the same as the one for S'. What if I need to append to S and S' the same elements over time but they may differ in ordering? Is there any specific commitment scheme best suited for this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

The point of a commitment scheme is that the commitment doesn't reveal what has been comitted to until the prover releases some secret information. For hash based shemes generally the comitment is `C=H(R+V)` where `R` is a large (128 bit) random number. An attacker can't check a guess for the value `V` without knowing `R`.

For a Merkle tree vector commitment scheme, leaves in the Merkle tree would be commitments on the values. Each leaf in the tree is calculated as `leaf[i]=Ci=H(Ri+Vi)`. A commitment for `[A,B,C,D,A,B,C,D]` would use different random `Ri` values for each leaf. Despite the values in the left and right sub-trees being identical (`[A,B,C,D]`) the leaf values and resulting subtrees are different.

There's optimizations that can be made in the implementation, Appending values to the list, requires only adding a new leaf to the merkle tree for example. Less obviously, the `Ri` values can be constructed using a binary tree to reduce the data size associated with the `Ri` sequence when revealing a slice of the value array.

Answer (score -2):

Simply store the individually commited values in a public medium such as blockchain. Verifier can then scrape everything that looks like your commitment and lookup opened commitments in a hash table.

It is how haircomb commitment set operates.